# Find the matrix of the given transfomation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x,y$ be linearly independent vectors is $\mathbb{R}^2$ suppose $T:\mathbb{R}^2\mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$ is a linear transformation such that $Ty=\alpha x$ and $Tx=0$ then with respect to some basis in $\mathbb{R}^2$ , then $T$ is of the form??
I fixed the basis $x,y$ are standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ but I get the matrix $\left(
               \begin{array}{cc}
                 0 & 0 \\
                 \alpha & -2\alpha \\
               \end{array}
             \right)$ I don't know it is right??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x,y$ is linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which has dimension $2$, $x,y$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. We have $Tx = 0x+0y$ and $Ty = \alpha x+0y$ and so the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $x,y$ is
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{M}(T,(x,y)) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0&\alpha\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: the above u defined $Tx=0x+0y$  here rhs $x$ and lhs $x$ both are same?

Comment: Actually $Tx = 0$ as you said. I just write $0$ as a linear combination of the basis $x,y$ and thus the entries of the matrix are found.

Comment: Oh wow ...now I understood.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is not right.

Hint: fix the basis as you did and calculate the matrix in this basis
$$
T[x\ y]=[x\ y]\begin{bmatrix}?_{11} & ?_{12}\\?_{21} & ?_{22}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Try to find out all $?$-positions from what you know above ($Ty=\alpha x$ and $Tx=0$).

Comment: Sorry I didn't get...can u pls explain

Comment: @GopiS If $Tx=0=[x\  y]\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ then the first column of the matrix must be zeros. After that if $Ty=\alpha x=[x\ y]\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ the the second column is $\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$. This is how you get $\Big[\text{first column}\ \text{ second column}\Big]=\begin{bmatrix}0 & \alpha\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$